# Are page caching and cache tags related?

Tags: 8, caching

I'm working with a site which has page cache enabled.

I'd like the page cache for any given node to invalidate when that node is changed. There's a lot of examples out there dealing with cache tags, but I haven't had any luck figuring out the relationship between page caching and cache tags.

I've got a node which starts out being published. I then unpublish it, and publish it again. When I publish it for the second time, the page cache still treats it as unpublished. It does so until i clear the entire (page) cache.

It seems that the `cache_page` entry is updated when i update a published node, but whenever the node goes from unpublished to published - the page cache entry doesn't follow.

I've tried implementing `hook_entity_update` and do a `Cache::invalidateTags(['node:19']);`, but that had no impact.

Is it possible to use cache tags to invalidate page cache entries?

Comment: `I'd like the page cache for any given node to invalidate when that node is changed.` – that's already built in. But it depends how and where exactly this node is being displayed. You probably need to update your question clarifying that.

Comment: @leymannx updated question to reflect that. If this is already built in, it may be a bug then.

Comment: Are you on the node view or are you talking about for example a view where the node is displayed?

Comment: You didn't add how the node is being displayed. The cache tags only invalidate cache for things when the tags are appropriately added to render arrays.

Comment: @sanzante it's a plain node view. No views or anything else fancy involved.

Comment: Can you add which page caching modules you have enabled, also whether there are any external cache mechanisms, e.g. varnish.

Comment: I bet a hundred bucks some server-side caching is causing the issue.

Comment: @leymannx as far as I can tell, when you unpublish a node, the `cache_table` entry for that node's url alias has it's tags cleared and checksum set to 0. When you publish the node again, Drupal cannot invalidate the page cache entry because there are no tags to target. So the page cache entry is just hanging out there, resulting in stale content.

At least that what seems to be happening here.

Comment: @sonf running this in a local docker environment, so nothing else than nginx and php involved.

Comment: Which version of drupal? Which cache modules are in use? Does this happen on a fresh install of drupal? Does this happen with the bartik theme? Do you have custom code rendering or saving nodes? Do you have custom caching code? Please check these things and add all of the information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Page cache is just the cached values.

Cache tags are tags that are attached to a cached value (simplifying a little bit). This tells Drupal what cached values are related to what cache tags. When a cache tag is invalidated, all cached values that have the invalidated cache tag are invalidated as well. You can find more info on the Drupal documentation page about [Cache Tags](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags). The headline is:

> Cache tags provide a declarative way to track which cache items depend
> on some data managed by Drupal.

So, answering your question, yes, they are totally related and you can (and you should) invalidate page cache entries using cache tags. Because, as stated above, cache tags track content and cache dependencies and thus you can invalidate cached item when content (or the source data of a cached item) changes.

However, this can be tricky. For example, page cache entry of a node view page is always associated with the cache tag `node:[nid]`. When the node is updated, that cache tag is invalidated, thus making the page cache of that node's view page invalidated as well. Views that shows a list of nodes are not associated with each node's cache tag. Blocks are other display elements may not be related to that kind of tags. So you need to know which cache tag you want to invalidate.

The good news is Drupal takes care of the most common cases, so you don't have to care. Usually, you only need to deal with the cache tags when you are developing custom code.

In your case, you may be hitting another cache (browser cache? reverse proxy cache?).

Comment: It seems that when you unpublish a node, the page cache sets the checksum for the node's url alias to 0 and removes all tags in the `cache_page` table.

If you publish the node again, there are no tags in `cache_page` to target. So the page cache table seems to just serve out stale content.

Comment: Yes, this could be the reason. But as @sanzante answered, Drupal takes care of the most common use cases. When you try to display an unpublished node and produce an access denied result this bubbles up the cache tag of the node to the page and Views filtering for the published status usually adds a `node_list` tag catching all node saves.